# Graphics card settings in bios menu

Tags: graphics-card, bios

I was looking at the default settings of my Graphics card in bios menu. The default is 32m I'm not sure what that means. The optional settings are 32m / 64m / 128m / 256m / 512m / .does it matter if I change it from 32m to 512m? So is it necessary to change the settings to be 512m?

Comment: Your question is confusing.  "This will help to speed ...?" and "What are the sides effect for this?" - are sort of broad questions. Can you narrow down the scope of your other questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I was looking at the default settings of my Graphics card in bios
>   menu. The default is 32m I'm not sure what that means. The optional
>   settings are 32m / 64m / 128m / 256m / 512m / .does it matter if I
>   change it from 32m to 512m?

The setting controls how much VRAM your intergrated GPU will have access to.  For the purposes fo this option the unit is in Megabytes

> What are the sides effect for this?

The operating system will not have access, to whatever the amount of memory you assigned to your intergrated GPU, the memory will be reserved for hardware use.  It is worth pointing out that having more VRAM will not cause the GPU operate at a faster frequency it will operate at the same frequency it currently is set at, it will just have access to more VRAM.

Comment: Be aware that although more memory allocated to the GPU won't change the frequency at which it operates, having more memory reserved for the GPU can allow it perform better depending on how your using your computer and the screen resolution, especially in graphics intensive applications like gaming, and can reduce frame rate stutter, lagging texture fills, etc. Finding the proper size is a trial and error.

Comment: @acejavelin - I made specific mention of the frequency for that reason.  I also specifically tried to stay away from any statement surrounding any possible gains or lose in performance with regard to how much VRAM the GPU has access to, because I don't know what the user is attempting to run, so that is a rabbit hole I decided to stay away from on purpose.